# Form - Getting blank return values after submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

im trying to populate the form input value into a new window pop-up, for that im using window.open method. I managed to get the pop up widdow however, the input were not passed through, the page return with no value. Kindly advise how to fix this. Thanks in advance. Im new to web devolpment.

script

```
function validate(){ <!-- HTML form validation done by JavaScript.  -->

<!-- variable object used to represent the questions in the form  -->

var x1=document.getElementById("text1");
var x2=document.getElementById("text2");
var x3=document.getElementById("hobbies");
var x4=document.getElementById("Gender");


<!-- if used to verify if no information given the the alert will pop up upon submission -->
if (x1.value == "" || x2.value == "" || x3.value == "" || x4.value == "") 

{
alert("No blank values allowed")
return false;
}
else
{
window.open('https://quiet-odyssey-258110.appspot.com/'+self.location,'mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
}

}

</script>
```

form

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()">

<!-- label used to tag the field name -->
<label>Full Name : </label>
<input type= "text" id="text1" name= "text1" placeholder="Enter your Full Name here..."><br>

<label>Email address : </label>
<input type= "email" id="text2" name= "email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address here..." ><br><br>

<label>Hobbies : </label><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" name="hobbies[]" value="Reading"/>Reading<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" name="hobbies[]" value="Painting"/>Painting<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" name="hobbies[]" value="Traveling"/>Traveling<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" name="hobbies[]" value="Baking"/>Baking<br/><br/>

<label>Gender</label><br><br>  <!-- drop donw list has been used to choose gender and locations -->
     <input type="radio" id="Gender" name="gender" value="Male" > Male<br>
    <input type="radio" id="Gender" name="gender" value="Female"> Female<br>
    </select><br>




    </hr>
    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn" >Register</button>
    <button type="reset" class="Reset">Reset</button>


</form>
```

PHP

```
Congratulations !!!<br/><br/>
Your Full Name : <?php echo $_GET["text1"]; ?><br/>
Your Email address : <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?><br/>
Your Hobbies : <?php foreach($_GET['hobbies'] as $selected){
echo $selected.", ";};?><br/>
Your Gender : <?php echo $_GET["gender"]; ?><br/>
```

Comment: check your `id` name & the name you are calling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed adding values onto the URL.

window.open('https://quiet-odyssey-258110.appspot.com/`?text1='+ x1 +'&email='+x2+'`,'mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get params with `$_GET["text1"]` but not passing them in the `window.open` url querystring.
To have something in `$_GET["text1"]` you should have something like `?text1=some_value` in your url

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the method of form submit. First, you mention Your method in your HTML code.

```
 <form onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" action="">

<!-- label used to tag the field name -->
<label>Full Name : </label>
<input type= "text" id="text1" name= "text1" placeholder="Enter your Full Name here..."><br>

<label>Email address : </label>
<input type= "email" id="text2" name= "email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address here..." ><br><br>

<label>Hobbies : </label><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" name="hobbies[]" value="Reading"/>Reading<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" name="hobbies[]" value="Painting"/>Painting<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" name="hobbies[]" value="Traveling"/>Traveling<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="hobbies" name="hobbies[]" value="Baking"/>Baking<br/><br/>

<label>Gender</label><br><br>  <!-- drop donw list has been used to choose gender and locations -->
     <input type="radio" id="Gender" name="gender" value="Male" > Male<br>
    <input type="radio"
    </hr>
    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn" >Register</button>
    <button type="reset" class="Reset">Reset</button>   

</form>
```

If your method GET then Get Result SomethingLike:

```
Your Full Name : <?php echo $_GET["text1"]; ?><br/>
Your Email address : <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?><br/>
Your Hobbies : <?php foreach($_GET['hobbies'] as $selected){
echo $selected.", ";};?><br/>
Your Gender : <?php echo $_GET["gender"]; ?><br/>
```

If your method POST then Get Result Something Like:

```
    Your Full Name : <?php echo $_POST["text1"]; ?><br/>
    Your Email address : <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?><br/>
    Your Hobbies : <?php foreach($_POST['hobbies'] as $selected){
    echo $selected.", ";};?><br/>
    Your Gender : <?php echo $_POST["gender"]; ?><br/>
```

If you using JavaScript Then Your post answer variable should be pass with URL Like this

```
    window.location.href =
 URL?text1="+text1+"&email="+email+"&hobbies="+hobbies+"+&gender="+gender+"
```